# find class instance by property in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I'd like to retrieve an instance of some js Class with only the value of a parameter

lets say :

```
function myClass(id)
{
  this.id = id
}

myClass.prototype.sayHello = function()
{
  alert('hello');
}

myClass.instanceFromID = function()
{
  ...
}

var instance1 = new myClass(22);
var instance2 = new myClass(33);
var instance3 = new myClass(232);
var instance4 = new myClass(1533);
```

I would love to be able to access the instance by some method like

```
myClass.instanceFromID(33).sayHello();
```

I've been thinking of 2 solutions but **they seam overkill** :

### First idea:

storing all the instances in an array, (global scope or static to the class) and iterating over all of them to find and return the instance, but this implies to keep track, add and remove the instances from the array.

### Second idea:

make each instance listen to a custom event triggered from the document and compare the data emitted with inner parameter to check if it is concerned and emit a signal back to the document.

How can I achieve this in a simple way or is there no other way than these 2?

Comment: And your questions is...?

Comment: well, how to retrieve an instance of some js Class with only the value of a parameter

Comment: You've suggested two ways.  Both would work, with some caveats.  Are you looking for feedback on which is better?  Are you looking for alternative suggestions?

Comment: well, alternative suggestions, I feel like these 2 ideas are overkill and that there must be some simple way to achieve this I do not know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you've written, having the class itself keep track of instances with an instance variable seems to be the approach you're looking for.  Of course, this means that instances will never be garbage collected unless you explicitly release them.  But perhaps that isn't an issue for you.  Here's how I would tackle this:

```
function MyClass(id) {
    this.id = id;
    MyClass.instances[id] = this;
}
MyClass.instances = {};
MyClass.instanceFromId = function(id) {
    return MyClass.instances[id];
}
```

Comment: Right you are.  Fixed.

Comment: ID is not generated, it is known in forehand (id from a sql table) and can be a large number, like 342881

Comment: That's fine, it doesn't change the approach.  Just pass in the ID instead.

Comment: assuming since we are saying ID you will never have 2 of the same ID correct? @VincentDuprez

Comment: Modified answer given your approach (IDs are supplied).

Comment: yes, never 2 the same, I was afraid of having empty 'slots' in a huge array if the only item in the array is, let's say: index # 342881 ...

Comment: I used an object, not an array, so there will be no empty "slots" in an array.

Comment: Ethan can you explain how this returns the correct instance? ** NVM ** I figured it out ... looked at it so wrong....

Comment: oh yes, I misread that. seams alright then! I'll go that way.

Comment: Cayce, can you explain what your confusion is?  The object instances are stored in a keyed object, and the instance is returned by its ID....

Comment: And with the later changes, of course `nextId` is now unnecessary.

Comment: Good catch, Scott, fixed.